# Excel: create an array with a formula

Tags: excel

I need to calculate in a sheet this function

```
=a+sa+s^2a+..+s^na
```

where n is an integer defined in a cell (for example: A1)

to do this i think to use "=SERIESUM" function but it wants an argument (coefficients) predeterminated!

how can i create an array of n coefficients to use in my SERIESUM function without VBA code?

Comment: Actually, do you have a sample table to show what exactly is that you have?

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the help on [seriessum](http://excelfunctions.net/Excel-Seriessum-Function.html) you will notice that coefficients can be an array so you could enter

> =seriessum(5,1,A1,A2:A10)

With you coefficients being in A2 through A10.

Comment: I can't use a set of cells for the coefficients because this formula is very frequently on my sheet with many "n"

Comment: how do you need to put in coefficients?  You can also put them in the formula using curly brackets {1,2,3,5,6,3,...,2}

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the offset function to create your coefficient range.

If you put your coefficients in column A starting at A1, and then make your n values column B, column C would contain =sereiessum(x-value, 0, 1, offset($A$1, 0, 0, B1, 1))

The 0 and 1 are the starting exponent (0) and step size.  Offset will give you a range starting 0 cells below and 0 cells right of $A$1 and will be N cells long and 1 wide.  your n values should be the number of elements you want not the exponent you want to raise to.